# Check if a string has a word followed by a number

Tags: java, string

I have strings like:

```
    String test="top 10 products";
    String test2="show top 10 products";
```

Is there a way to check if the word "top" has a number following it?  If so, how to get that number to another string?

I'm thinking about using `indexOf("top")` and add 4 to  that and try to get the next word. Not sure how it will work. Any suggestions?

Comment: why don't you try to use regular expressions?

Comment: Did you even try to search for an existing question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to extract a possible number after single / first occurrence of "top", that's a viable way. Don't forget to check for existence of the word, and that there's something behind it at all.

You can also use regular expression for this, which will need a bit less error checking:

```
top\\s+([0-9]+)
```

You could even make a `Pattern` out of this, and then iterate the `Matcher.find()` method and extract the numbers for multiple matches:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("top\\s+([0-9]+)");
Matcher matcher = pat.matcher("top 10 products or top 20 products");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: The Matcher.find() is doing the exact job that I require. Thanks a Lot Jiri

Answer (score 0):

An evil regex can help you.

```
    String test="top 10 products";
    System.out.println(test.replaceAll(".*?\\w+\\s+(\\d+).*", "$1"));
```

O/P :

```
10
```

Note : This will return the entire String in case there is no "Word[space]digits" in the String. You will have to do a length check for the actual String and the returned String. If the length is same, then your String doesn't contain the expected pattern.